# how to extract the desired lines after matching the text in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

**Input file:**

```
{test test
{***********************************************************************
{Rtest
{***********************************************************************
{test
{***********************************************************************
{* date
{*
{* Initial revision
{*
{***********************************************************************

{output}

{output1}

{output 2}

{Test TEst TEST}  
{Test test test}

{*********************}

{********************}
```

**Required Output:**

```
{Output}
{output1}
{output2}
```

**Script**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  $line = $_;
  chomp $line;

  push( @lines, $line );

  $line =~ s/^\s+//;
  $line =~ s/\s+$//;

  for ( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#lines ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $lines[$i] =~ m/(^{\**$)/ ) {

      push( @matched, $lines[ $i + 1 ] );
      print "$lines[$i+1]"."\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**my output:**

```
 {test test
    {***********************************************************************
    {Rtest
    {***********************************************************************
    {test
    {***********************************************************************
    {* date
    {*
    {* Initial revision
    {*
    {***********************************************************************
```

I am able to match the top block, but unable to get the required first 3 lines as output. From the above match condition i am trying to extract the next line but i get a white space as the output.
Am i missing something, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not work with `use strict`. There are lots of `requires explicit package name` errors. Also, you have `$line` redefined.

Comment: It would be _very_ helpful if you write down the specific conditions that are matched by your `output` lines. Right now, as I see it, it can be either 'the first three lines in the file that are matched by `/^\{[^{]*}$/` pattern', or 'the lines that are separated from the the other lines by empty strings and don't contain '*' symbol'. It shouldn't be like that: we don't have to _guess_ what you want.

Comment: @raina77ow from the condition i have obtained the  o/p as mentioned, i thought i would get the first 3 lines with the match but i got only white space which is just before the first line of the required output. i tried to remove the blank lines so that i can get the first line, but it didnt solved..

Comment: That code won't compile and certainly didn't produce the output you say it did.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** After the last edit, this answer is not valid anymore because the OP has changed the desired output.

This can be done very simply. Just remove all the lines that start with a curly `{` and the ones that are empty.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @output;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;           # remove newline
  next if /^\{\*/; # We don't want lines starting with an open curly and an asterisk
  next if /^\s*$/; # We also do not want lines that are empty
  push @output, $_;
}

print Dumper \@output;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'output',
          'output1',
          'output 2'
        ];
```

Comment: sinbabque: thanks for the output, but i have edited the requird output which should cointain the curly braces as we cannot skip them.

Comment: Or just `egrep -v '^($|\{\*)' file`

Comment: @tripleee: I like that one! But the `\*` is not needed here. There are lines like `{test` in the input that the OP did not want in his output.

Comment: @simbabque: nice that you don't even need to solve the problem to get upvotes! :P

Comment: Haha, he must have changed the question. xD If you look at the first revision, my answer actually fits... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This program is my best guess at what you may want. It expects the input file on the command line.

I have written it so that it prints the next three non-blank lines after a line beginning with `{*`. But I cannot fathom what rule would exclude the lines

```
{Rtest
```

and

```
{test
```

but include the ones you say you want. Please ask again if you need anything further.

**Update**

Perhaps you want to print only those lines that *end* with `}`? I have changed my code to do that instead

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;
my @matched;

my $n = 0;

while (<>) {
  if ( /^\s*\{\*+/ ) {
    $n = 3;
  }
  elsif ( $n and /\}\s*$/ ) {
    print;
    $n-- ;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
{output}
{output1}
{output 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're going back through a backlog of lines and repeatedly shoving them into `@matched`--especially when they don't *match* the output you say you're trying to get. This does better...

```
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    print if m/^[{]o/i;
}
```

but it doesn't achieve your specified output, because there is no input lines corresponding to `'{Output}'` or `'{output2}'` only `'{output}'` and `'{output 2}'`, so, just in case it's not just sloppy specification, we may have to revise it.

```
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    next unless my ( $n ) = m/^[{]output\s*(\d)?[}]/i;
    my $output = length $n ? 'output' : 'Output';
    say "{$output$n}";
}
```